# Stream flatMap vs map

Tags: java, collections, java-8, stream

To filter a `List` we can use

```
a1.stream().filter(x->x>6).forEach(System.out::println);
```

and to filter two lists I used `FlatMap`

```
Stream<List<Integer>> s2=Stream.of(a1,a2);
s2.flatMap(x->x.stream()).sorted().filter(x->x>6).forEach(System.out::println);
```

but I tried filtering in this way for a single `List`

```
Stream<List<Integer>> s1=Stream.of(a1);
s1.map(x->x.stream()).filter(x->x>2).forEach(System.out::print);
```

I got an error--- `The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) Stream<Integer>, int`

but when I use the flatMap in the map no error why

```
Stream<List<Integer>> s1=Stream.of(a1); 
s1.flatMap(x->x.stream()).filter(x->x>2).forEach(System.out::print);
```

Comment: Both `s2` and `s1` are streams of `List`, so why did you expect that `s1.map()` would do the same as `s2.flatMap()`?

Comment: Map is for one result only.  Flatmap are for zero or more results.

Comment: To stream over a single list, use `a1.stream()` instead of `Stream.of(a1)`. Then, you need neither, `map` nor `flatMap`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are calling `map(x->x.stream())` on a `Stream<List<Integer>>`, you'll get a `Stream<Stream<Integer>>`. You cannot apply `.filter(x->x>2)` on the elements of that `Stream`, since those elements are `Stream<Integer>`s, and the `>` operator requires two numeric operands.

If you use `flatMap` instead of `map`, you are converting your `Stream<List<Integer>>` to a `Stream<Integer>` whose elements are all the elements of all the `List`s of the original `Stream`. Therefore, you can apply the `.filter(x->x>2)` filter on them.

Comment: Stream<List<Integer>> s1=Stream.of(a1);

s1.filter(x->x>2).forEach(System.out::print);

error--The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) List<Integer>, int

Comment: @Krissag well, in this case the elements of your `Stream` are `List<Integer>`. You cannot ask if a `List<Integer>` > 2.

Answer (score 2):

```
Stream<List<Integer>> s1 = Stream.of(a1);
        s1.map(x -> x.stream()).filter(x -> x > 2).forEach(System.out::print);
```

This will give error as you are not using flat map so filtering not possible whole (Streams >2). You can try like this:

```
    Stream<List<Integer>> s1 = Stream.of(a1);
            s1.map(x -> x.stream()).filter(x -> x.findFirst().get() > 2).forEach(System.out::print);
```

As we cannot `apply.filter(x->x>2)` on we will requires two numeric operands. `s1.map(x -> x.stream()).filter(x -> x.findFirst().get() > 2).forEach(System.out::print);` if we will take this then filter will find find matching element value which is greater than 2. In short we have to use flatmap to find greater than 2 in those streams or any operation to fetch numeric operands from stream then only it work.

Comment: Explain your code or at least write a few words about it

Comment: As we cannot apply .filter(x->x>2) on we will requires two numeric operands.   s1.map(x -> x.stream()).filter(x -> x.findFirst().get() > 2).forEach(System.out::print); if we will take this then filter will find find matching element value which is greater than 2. In short  we  have to use flatmap to  find greater than 2 in those streams or  any operation to fetch numeric operands from  stream then only it work.

Comment: @murari99732 I just formatted you answer, if you do like fell free to rollback :)